# Diminuir a precisão do float em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, matemática, float

Como diminuir as casas decimais de um número float no javascript?

Por exemplo, quero que `3.3333333333` se torne em `3.34`.

Qual é a maneira mais simples de se fazer isso no `javascript`?

Tentei funções como `Math.ceil`, porém ela me retorna o valor inteiro.

```
float_value = 3.333333;
Math.ceil(float_value); // 4
```

Comment: Também dá para usar o `.toPrecision()` http://jsfiddle.net/cks2mvr9/

Comment: @qmechanik, você deveria postar como resposta, pra ganhar +1, rsrsrsrsrsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) que retorna o valor do número inteiro mais próximo.

`Math.round(num * 100) / 100`

Você também pode usar a função [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
parseFloat("123.456").toFixed(2); // Se for uma string, converta pra numéro
```

Comment: Fino, amigo. Mas eu gostaria de saber se no `Javascript` tem alguma forma de fazer nativamente?

Comment: Acredito que uma função nativa pra isso não tenha, acho que só na mão mesmo, :)

Comment: Você também pode usar o toFixed...

Comment: Não me acostumei com isso ainda: No javascript puro, muita coisa é na mão ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) pra fazer isso, mas ele retorna uma `String`, e não um `float`. Do próprio site:

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

resulta em

```
5.57
```

Tem uma discussão sobre isso no [SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453421/how-to-round-float-numbers-in-javascript).

Comment: Obrigado, Caio. Eu tinha pensando no `.toFixed`, porém ele retorna uma string. Mas, nesse caso, eu apenas teria que utilizar `parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))`

Comment: É uma volta, mas funciona!

Comment: Logo temos: http://jsfiddle.net/mqzbsgxf/